# Primefaces global tooltip with HTML content

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

In my JSF page I am using a datatable with tooltip on a row column like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="item" ...>
  <p:column headerText="#{bundle['item.name']}">
    <!--
    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" title="#{simpleTooltipGenerator.generate(item)}"/>
    -->
    <h:outputText id="name" value="#{item.name}"/>
    <p:tooltip for="name" escape="false" value="#{simpleTooltipGenerator.generate(item)}"/>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The `simpleTooltipGenerator.generate()` is a method which generates the following HTML tooltip:

```
<div class="ui-tooltip-text ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td class="key">Lastname</td><td class="value">Doe</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="key">Firstname</td><td class="value">John</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="adresse spacer"></div>
  <div class="adresse title">Address</div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td class="key">OFFICE</td><td class="value">...</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="key">HOME</td><td class="value">...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This works as expected, but when I use a global tooltip `<p:tooltip escape="false"/>` together with `<h:outputText value="#{item.name}" title="#{simpleTooltipGenerator.generate(item)}"/>` only the generated HTML code is shown in the tooltip! Using a fixed text for the global tooltip works?!

Is this a bug, that global tooltip does not support HTML content, even if set `escape="false"`, or is this not supported?!

My environment is Primefaces 6.0 on WildFly 10.0.0-Final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PrimeFaces Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A543%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C56.7%2C773.3%2C0%5D):

> **Global Tooltip**
>
> ...
>   As global tooltips are more efficient
>   since only one instance of tooltip is used across all tooltip targets, it is suggested to be used instead
>   of explicit tooltips **unless you have a custom case e.g.** different options, **custom content**.

First I would say this is not supported. As i tried it worked nevertheless. So your problem seems to be missing *globalSelector* attribute which defaults to `a,:input,:button`

If you want to support `<h:outputText />` (which renders as `<span />`) binding, just add a propper selector like:

```
<p:tooltip escaped="false" globalSelector="a,:input,:button,span" />
```

Comment: Adding the missing _globalSelector_ attribute as mentioned by @irieill solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the tooltip when used as presented in the question is that the tooltip does not support lazy loading of content (or I don't know how). Thus, the content of the tooltip is already generated when the table is drawn on the screen, which is not exactly desirable when there is a large amount of data and a long tooltip. We don't save much by using the global tooltip, since the title is already generated with data too!