# how to display bullet points in separate lines inside a tooltip box in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, tooltip

i am working on a javaEE based web application, which is using the primefaces framework. i need to display a long message arranged in bullets form in separate lines inside a tooltip. 
the message is being fetched from a java properties file. I have tried using the new line chars, i.e. \n OR \r, in order to display each bullet in a new line, but it didn't workout.
what do i do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889948/primefaces-global-tooltip-with-html-content

Comment: Generalize questions.... search for 'html' in tooltips, or 'pre formatted'... this helps